# Why I cannot check the MS word paragraph style in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

This is an addin to my MS word:

```
Public Sub Application_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.DocumentBeforeSave
    If SaveAsUI = True Then
            MsgBox(doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Style)
     End If
End Sub
```

When I run this on visual studio it says "argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'". However, when I run

```
MsgBox(activedocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Style)
```

on VBA inside MS word it shows me "Paper-Title", which is what I am looking for.  Can anyone help me with this on Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

As @mat says, your VBA program is silently taking advantage of VBA's implicit conversions and possibly the default-property of the `Style` object.

According to MSDN, the `Style` object is this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193692.aspx

It looks like you'll want the `NameLocal` property, so change your code to this:

```
Public Sub Application_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal doc As Word.Document, ByRef saveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.DocumentBeforeSave
    If saveAsUI AndAlso doc.Paragraphs.Count >= 2 Then
        MsgBox( doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Style.NameLocal )
     End If
End Sub
```

Note that your program will crash if the current document has less than 2 paragraphs, so I added a bounds-check for you.

Answer (score 1):

VBA is doing implicit conversions for you. .NET simply isn't as forgiving (although I'm not sure to what extent VB.NET allows or forbids those).

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.style.aspx) it looks like you're passing an `Object` to the `Prompt` parameter of the `MsgBox` function, which wants a `String`.

You'll want to call `.ToString()` on it before you pass it to the message box.

Also I believe having `Option Strict` on might be helpful here.